# Copy string without knowing size

Tags: c, arrays

Is there a way of copying a string into a new string without knowing the size that the new array has to be at compile time? As far as I am aware, you can't have variable array lengths in C.

For example:

```
void myFunction(char *string)
{
   char newString[????];

   strcopy(newString, string);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
void myFunction(char *string)
{
   char *newString = strdup (string);
   ... (make use of newString) ...
   free (newString);
}
```

This works with any version of C—even back to v6 Unix (1975).

Comment: Note `strdup` is not described by the Standard. It is described by POSIX. ... and you need to `free` the value obtained from `strdup` when you no longer need it

Comment: Your last point is a good one.  I assumed the OP would examine the man page for `strdup()`, but it is good practice to provide such information here.    As for your first point—who cares if it is POSIX or K&R?  The OP didn't ask for "standard" ways, just "a way".

Answer (score 4):

In C99, variable-length arrays are an option:

```
void myFunction(char *string)
{
   char newString[strlen(string) + 1];

    // note: strcpy, not strcopy
   strcpy(newString, string);
}
```

However, you'll run into problems if the string is large; it'll exhaust your stack space and kaboom! (Also, the array ceases to exist at the end of its scope, like any local variable, so you can't return it.)

So unless you know the string is small, you're probably better off just dynamically allocating:

```
void myFunction(char *string)
{
   char *newString = strdup(string);
   if (!newString) /* error */

   /* ... */

   free(newString);
}
```

Comment: Not marked down but shouldn't it be strlen + 1 for the termination character?

Comment: (even before C99, alloca was an option)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is a null-terminated string. So you can use strlen() to get the size of the string. Thus you can do this:

```
void myFunction(char *string)
{
   int len;
   char* newString;

   len = strlen(string);
   newString = (char*)malloc(len+1); // space for null termination too

   strcpy(newString, string);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1. (Also, just use `strdup`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <error.h>

typedef struct
{
   int ii;
   double dd;
} SSS;

int main()
{
   int kk, jj;

   char *str1="This is a text string";
   char *str2 = malloc(strlen(str1));

   SSS *s1 = calloc(4, sizeof(SSS));
   if(s1 == ENOMEM) printf("Error ENOMEM: Insufficient memory available\n");

   strcpy(str2,str1); /* Make a copy of the string */

   for(kk=0; kk < 5; kk++)
   {
      s1[kk].ii=kk;
   }

   for(jj=0; jj < 5; jj++)
   {
      printf("Value strored: %d\n",s1[jj].ii);
   }

   free(s1);
   free(str2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have only done a bit in C, but I think from memory to get the size of a string I think you can do either. One of those works im sure. (dont hold it against me if I'm wrong :/)

```
sizeof(newString)
```

or

```
sizeof(newString) / sizeof(*newString)
```

Comment: If `newString` were an array, the latter would work. But it's a pointer.

Comment: strings are arrays of characters though aren't they?

Comment: String literals are arrays, yes, but `char*` would be a pointer to the first element, not an array.